# How to extract literally just 2 lines from a file

Tags: c

I am writing a program in C. I use low level functions like open, read, close. I have a file descriptor, etc, but I don't know how to print only the first 2 lines from a file that has e.g. 30 lines of text. how to do it?

Comment: Big problems are just collections of small problems. What have you attempted to read _one_ line from a file?

Comment: use [`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read a single line, use it twice to read two lines. If you're using [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) to read bytes, you'll need to looks for line endings to determine when you've read two lines.

Comment: What is a "line"? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(text_file)

Comment: @yano I've prefered to do that by low level functions, but ur method works so thank you!

Comment: Either use `fopen`/`fgets` or if you are required/want to use only `open`/`read`, write your own `myfgets` based on `read` and proceed.

Answer (score -1):

you need to read a file into a string, iterate through the string, concat any character into the string variable, define a int variable for lines count, when lines reaches 2, break the loop

here’s an example how you can do it

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char *get_first_two_lines(char *file_name) {
    FILE *file = fopen(file_name, "r");
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char *buffer = malloc(size);
    fread(buffer, 1, size, file);
    char *two_lines = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
    unsigned int lines = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(buffer);i++) {
        if (lines == 2) break;
        if (buffer[i] == '\n') {
            if (lines < 1) {
                two_lines = realloc(two_lines, (strlen(two_lines) + 2) * sizeof(char));
                strcat(two_lines, (char []) {'\n', 0});
            }
            lines++;
            continue;
        }
        two_lines = realloc(two_lines, (strlen(two_lines) + 2) * sizeof(char));
        strcat(two_lines, (char []) {buffer[i], 0});
    }
    return two_lines;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *first_two_lines = get_first_two_lines("file_name");
    printf("%s", first_two_lines);
    return 0;
}
```